# Wi-Fi disabled after initial install Centos 9 strm

Tags: wireless-networking

During installation Wi-Fi works, and I am able to select it as my nic, but after the initial reboot the OS comes up without error, but only ethernet works. WiFi hardware is not listed. I have checked that the WiFi card is enabled in bios, and even disabled the manual WiFi switch in bios. I tried installing on a different laptop and WiFi works ok.

Comment: Installation of which OS? Which NIC? Do you have any logs or errors?
Update your question with more details.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.